# Do the badges on Stack Overflow change from year to year?

Tags: discussion, badges

I get to know that there were a few other badges are available on Stack Overflow, but when I see the available list of badges in my profile it seems like those badges are not available. Are those badges are specific to log in or user type or do those badges are changing year to year?

For Example: **Publicist** badge

This is a **GOLD** badge which I can get based on the publicity/sharing of my post, but I can not see that badge in my profile's badge list.

[image: My Profile Badge List]

[image: Actual StackOverFlow Badge Collection]

Is there any way or approach to get this badge in my profile?

Comment: This is the list of available badges: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges (which includes the publicist badge). In which list did you look?

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of where you are looking and where you expect to see it?  The badge list in your profile is the badges you have earned, while the list that BDL linked is the list of all available badges

Comment: @BDL I go through that link and found the extra badges which are not in my profile badge list. https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist

Comment: The list of badges has changed historically, with some being removed and others added, but year to year they generally stay the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is a GOLD badge which I can get based on the publicity/sharing of my post, but I can not see that badge in my profile's badge list.

That is because in the *select next badge* dialog you only get offered badges you can earn yourself by contributing one way or the other. The publicist badge doesn't qualify for that. You can share a link to your post but after that you can only wait. Worst case you never earn that publicist badge no matter how often you put that link out in the wild.

From [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#188733):

> Share a link to a post that is visited by 1000 unique IP addresses
>
> In order to get credit for a certain click, the link must be a short-form link that contains your user ID (e.g. https://$site/[q|a]/[post ID]/[user ID]). Short links that don't contain the "user ID" portion and full-form links don't count. If you want to be sure a particular link counts, use the "share" button underneath the post.

Here is the share link for this meta question with my userid at the end:

> [image]

If I only had friends I could share that link with ...

Other badges you can't earn by contributing on your own are for example [Sheriff](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff) and  [Not a robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot). Those are not on that list in the dialog either.

Comment: can you let me know how exactly i can able to get this badge? What do you mean by publicist?

Comment: it says link : *Share a link to a post later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses*, so it mean i can get this badge only, share any post and then after visiting that shared post with minimum 1000 unique IP address. is it so?

Comment: @ankitkanojia Yes. Share a link on social media or somewhere, and wait for 1000 unique people to use the link. I've gotten the silver version of it by sharing posts on Reddit and Google+ (back when G+ existed).

Comment: Great, Thank you so much for guidance.